# How to Rewrite url in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am working for a site. My vps is nginx.
I want to rewrite link : https://vachnganvesinhgiare.com/feed.php to https://vachnganvesinhgiare.com/rss.xml

Plz Help me!

Comment: `rewrite ^/feed.php$ /rss.xml;`